# How to assign multiple variables inside a class?

Tags: php, class, variables, assign

How can I assign multiple variables at once in PHP? This is basically what I'm trying to achieve but it throws a parsing error on `private $from = private $to` saying `syntax error, unexpected 'private'`:

```
<?php
namespace Library;

class Localize
  {
  // Default data for both fields. Localization must be specified.
  private $from = private $to = array(
    'language' => 'en',     // Language: English
    'country'  => 'usa',    // Country: USA
    'currency' => 'dollar', // Currency: dollar $
    'units'    => 'is',     // Units: International System[meter, kelvin, etc]
    'timezone' => '-5'      // Timezone: UTC -5 hours [America/New_York]
    );

  // ...
  }
```

I've tried `private $from = private $to` and `private $from = $to` but both would throw an error. **What's the proper syntax for assigning multiple properties at once inside a PHP class?**

Note: I know there are many ways of dealing with this like the constructor, but I'd like to know if what I'm trying to achieve exactly is possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you like to do it that way? Think of a class as a pattern of an entity. This entity usually does not define any data. Data is handled with at the time you create a concrete object of your class. You usually assign values to your class members in the constructor of the class. So I would do the initialization in the constructor.

Comment: I normally use the constructor to assign the variables that I need to pass through arguments and assign the "configuration" variables automatically first, as I'm attempting here, instead of doing so in the constructor. Is this bad? I find it more logic: what is specific to the class goes with the class variables, what is specific with the object goes with the object initializer (the constructor).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, why you want to avoid the constructor. It is a valid and clean way to do what you want. Somewhat a separation of concerns. The class definition defines the pattern for objects of this class and the implementation of class methods perform data manipulation for a concrete instantiation of this class. Sure, there are multiple ways how to achieve a desired goal and additionally in PHP most ways might not result in concrete drawbacks. However, in other languages or in software construction in general some ways might be considered more "clean". Often a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Php syntax doesn't allow that, but you can do that in constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->to = clone $this->from;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better idea would be to use a single array to store all the properties of the class

```
private $_arLoc = array();
```

Then, assign values in constructor

```
$_arLoc[ 'from' ] = array(
    'language' => 'en',     // Language: English
    'country'  => 'usa',    // Country: USA
    'currency' => 'dollar', // Currency: dollar $
    'units'    => 'is',     // Units: International System[meter, kelvin, etc]
    'timezone' => '-5'      // Timezone: UTC -5 hours [America/New_York]
);

$_arLoc[ 'to' ] = $_arLoc[ 'from' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, you cannot. You will have to define them at instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?Depends on what you want to use it for.

```
class Localize
    {
    // Default data for both fields. Localization must be specified.


    private $to = array(
    'language' => 'en',     // Language: English
    'country'  => 'usa',    // Country: USA
    'currency' => 'dollar', // Currency: dollar $
    'units'    => 'is',     // Units: International System[meter, kelvin, etc]
    'timezone' => '-5'      // Timezone: UTC -5 hours [America/New_York]
    );
    private $from ;

    function __construct(){
            $this->from = $this->to;
    }
    function __destruct(){

    }

    // ...
}

$var = new Localize();

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: I have that right now as a working solution, however I was curious if the work in the constructor could be avoided.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are already saying the $to array is private!

Try:
      private $from = $to = array(

Comment: I stated that this exactly didn't work for me in the question... it gives `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$to'`.

Comment: public function __construct() {
    $this->to = clone $this->from;
}